Jmeter adding numbers to csv labels
I have a jmeter script the reads login data from a csv, there are 100 rows of data.
The scenario is a stepped scenario which steps by 10 users every 120 seconds up to a total of 100 like so

The scenario is
jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group
**Login Process(simple Controller)
*****Login Page (Http Request)
*****Login Process (Http Request)
When running the test at command line like
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/save/results.csv -o -e /p/to/generated/report
Expected Results
CSV labels do not contain numbers
Results
CSV & Report Labels contain numbers up to 20 e.g. Login Page, Login Page 2.
I end up with multiple lines in a graph for the same sampler.
Each line has a numbered label
HELP Guys I'm stumped
Hope this makes sense :D

You mean like this?

it's absolutely expected so JMeter could handle i.e. embedded resources or Transaction Controller results.
In order to "group" the sub-results you can click "Export transactions for report" element from "Tools" menu:

Once you add the generate line to user.properties file and restart your test (or re-generate the report) you will see individual transactions details without sub-results.
